# Modal window background doesn`t resize properly

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a problem with modal window in my application. All is good, except when resizing modal window mask: when browser size decreases, they increase. Modal window mask stays at a smaller window size.

[image]

Here is my viewport

```
Ext.define('Bis.view.Viewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    layout: 'border',
    items: [{
            region: 'north',
            xtype: 'container',
            height: 100,
            layout: 'border',
            items:[{
                xtype: 'container',
                layout: 'border',
                region: 'north',
                height: 70,
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'container',
                    region: 'west',
                    styleHtmlCls: 'account-header-logo',
                    styleHtmlContent: true
                }, {
                    xtype: 'component',
                    region: 'center'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    itemId: 'userControlsContainer',
                    region: 'east'
                }]
            }, {
                region: 'center'
            }]

        }, {
            region: 'center',
            bodyStyle: 'background:#79b5d8;'
        }, {
            region: 'south',
            xtype: 'container',
            items:[{
                xtype: 'component',
                width: 150,
                styleHtmlCls: 'footer-logo',
                styleHtmlContent: true
            }]
         }
    ]
});
```

Modal window adding not to the viewport, but to the region: 'center'. When adding to the viewport, there are no such problems, but I need to add window to this region

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed the problem. It happens, because background is listening for global window resize event as viewport do. So, sometimes background mask does not resize to the right size. I used a fix similar to this (add this to overrides):

```
Ext.EventManager.removeResizeListener(Ext.WindowManager._onContainerResize, Ext.WindowManager);
Ext.EventManager.onWindowResize(Ext.WindowManager._onContainerResize, Ext.WindowManager, {delay: 5});
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more why this particular fix? It looks like you are only adding a delay, but would like to understand why this delay makes sense if you know. Thx

Comment: The actually trick is that in some cases Container Resize event start processing on the middle of your resize (for exampe you resize browser size on 70px and this event starts fires on 35 px and not fire at and.). Perhaps it is some bug, but delay allow you to finish resizing. In my case it works perfect in 99.99%

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the xtype and layout of the center region explicitly:

```
 {
    region: 'center',
    xtype: 'panel',
    layout: 'fit'    
 }
```

If this doesn't work, you might need to elaborate on how you are adding the modal window.